# how to capture that a value has changed in the database using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have spent the whole day trying to figure out how can I capture that a value in a specific column has changed in order to trigger some calculations. I am using C# and an MS Access database.

I have 3 columns in my database: time, strike and vol.

I am only interested if changes occur to the vol column so I can trigger calculations.

I looked at delegate and events, but I think there should be a much easier way of doing it.

Do you guys know how to go about that?

Many thanks !

Comment: are you checking for a change on one row, or any row?

Comment: I need to check if there is a change for every row in a specific column

Comment: Are the changes occurring outside of your program's control?

Comment: yes they could occur outside of my program's control. A person can manually change values of that specific column. I need to capture those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a local copy of the table in an array, then at regular intervals compare the access table  to the one you have in the array, then fire off your functionality if you detect a change.

Comment: I have actually thought about keeping local copy of the table in an array and checking at regular intervals. The thing is that I need to capture the change in real time and not at regular intervals ... what do you mean fire off my functionality?

Comment: i meant that you can then run whatever code you need when you detect a change. I think that because access is a file-based db, there isn't really anything running to trigger an event.

Comment: oh ok ! so I think I only can keep a local copy of the table in an array and checking at regular intervals. Do you know how can i check at regular intervals?

Comment: @Mike Put a timer in your application that calls a method every n seconds or minutes. The method will load the new copy of the values in the column you want to check, then compare them to the values stored previously. Any values that are different are the ones you need to do something with.

Answer (score 1):

While Access databases do not offer true TRIGGER features you might find a Data Macro helpful if you are working with Access 2010 or later. You could add a [volChanged] column (Yes/No, Indexed (duplicates OK)) and then create the following "Before Change" Data Macro:

```
If Updated("vol") Then
    SetField
        Name   volChanged
        Value  =True
End If
```

Once that macro is in place, a change to the [vol] field on any record will change the [volChanged] flag for that record to `True`. On a sample table with two records, both of which have [volChanged] set to `False`, the following Excel VBA code...

```
Sub volChangeTest()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM volTable WHERE volChanged", con
Debug.Print "[volChanged] is True for " & rst(0).Value & " record(s)"
rst.Close
sql = "UPDATE volTable SET vol = vol + 1"
Debug.Print sql
con.Execute sql
rst.Open "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM volTable WHERE volChanged", con
Debug.Print "[volChanged] is True for " & rst(0).Value & " record(s)"
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

...produces the following results:

```
[volChanged] is True for 0 record(s)
UPDATE volTable SET vol = vol + 1
[volChanged] is True for 2 record(s)
```

The Data Macro itself cannot trigger any external process, but because the [volChanged] field is small and indexed you can look for "updates" very frequently with minimal overhead, certainly less than maintaining a list of "old values" somewhere and using it to search for changes row-by-row.

Comment: @Mike I may be wrong but it sounds like the OP is writing a program to consume Access data rather than working directly from Access. I agree that the solution that the OP is looking for is going to require some Access-side programming, but I don't know that that is a possibility in this case. And if it is possible they're still going to be stuck with polling instead of an event-driven model.

Comment: @MichaelTodd Creating the Data Macro is the only Access-side programming required. Checking for updates would involve doing something like the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` statements in my sample code. That could be done from anywhere, like a C# app, or a Scheduled Task in Windows. Yes, they'd still be polling, but it would be considerably less expensive than it would be without the data macro, and a fully event-driven model is simply not available for an ACE back-end.